# Numpy: Imposing row dependent maximum on array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following array:

```
a = [[1, 4, 2, 3]
     [3, 1, 5, 4]
     [4, 3, 1, 2]]
```

What I'd like to do is impose a maximum value on the array, but have that maximum vary by row. For instance if I wanted to limit the 1st and 3rd row to a maximum value of 3, and the 2nd row to a value of 4, I could create something like:

```
[[1, 3, 2, 3]
 [3, 1, 4, 4]
 [3, 3, 1, 2]
```

Is there any better way than just looping over each row individually and setting it with 'nonzero'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) (using the method version here):

```
a.clip(max=np.array([3, 4, 3])[:, None]) # np.clip(a, ...)
# array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
#        [3, 1, 4, 4],
#        [3, 3, 1, 2]])
```

Generalized:

```
def clip_2d_rows(a, maxs):
    maxs = np.asanyarray(maxs)
    if maxs.ndim == 1:
        maxs = maxs[:, np.newaxis]
    return np.clip(a, a_min=None, a_max=maxs)
```

You might be safer using the module-level function (`np.clip`) rather than the class method (`np.ndarray.clip`).  The former uses `a_max` as a parameter, while the latter uses the builtin `max` as a parameter which is never a great idea.

Comment: Well, don't I feel stupid now, thanks for such a quick reply!

Comment: Also, this seems faster!

Comment: "while the latter uses the builtin `max` as a parameter which is never a great idea." What do you mean uses the  builtin `max` as a parameter?

Comment: strange that they use it then... Either way, I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga check the [syntax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.clip.html).  I guess it might be harmless, but usually see attempt to avoid using builtin names like that.  i.e. `def func(klass=None)`..

Answer (score 3):

With `masking` -

```
In [50]: row_lims = np.array([3,4,3])

In [51]: np.where(a > row_lims[:,None], row_lims[:,None], a)
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: This seems like a more flexible solution, but for the problem in specific Brad's answer seems more succinct and runs faster. Still, thanks! I'll have to look into masking more.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
>>> a
array([[1, 4, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 5, 4],
       [4, 3, 1, 2]])
```

Say you have

```
>>> maxs = np.array([[3],[4],[3]])
>>> maxs
array([[3],
       [4],
       [3]])
```

What about doing

```
>>> a.clip(max=maxs)
array([[1, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 1, 2]])
```